# Whatr size aerator pump is needed for a 500 gallon aerobic system?

Tags: septic

Our septic system was here when we bought the house and it is unbranded. the aerator pump above ground needs to be replaced.  How do we determine what size pump for a 500 gallon capacity aerobic system?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - check with the local health department or wherever septic plans are filed locally and see what your system was designed to have - the system design should be on file there from when it was permitted/approved.

Option 2 - hire a septic design engineer.

Option 1 should be free. Option 2 costs money. Pulling a number out of the hat on the internet is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Most homes are under 2500 sqft so they use a 500-600 gpd system.Most systems of this size use a 80 liter a min pump such as a Hiblow Hp80, Secoh EL-80,Fuji Mac80R2,a Gast AT05 will aslo work. The number at the end of most septic air pumps is the literes of air per min. As the systems get larger the pump size increases as more dissolved oxygen is needed to treat the waste water.

Answer (score -1):

80 Liters of air per minute is the standard size for a 500 gpd system.
Some systems use a rotary vane type aerator as well but these are less common do to cost and because they are a little louder.
The best aerators on the market are the Fuji Mac 80r2 3 year warranty, Hiblow HP-80 2 year warranty and used by most manufacturers of aerobic septic systems. Also the Secoh JDK-80 other great unit. Some 500 gpd systems use a 40 liter a minute pump but it’s rare and questionable when you have 80 percent of the systems using 80s.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your answer is hard to understand; editing it with full sentences would really help.

Comment: I've been asked to review your answer due to lack of information. Regardless of how tedious or basic it might seem, Editing your answer to include "according to such & such chart" or "Aerator Pumps work on such & such principle, so you need to figure blah-blah-blah." Is the kind of back-grounded answer that would be useful to this Asker & future searchers of the database. Thanks for being so precise though.